# Run PhpStorm's Create Project with sudo

Tags: phpstorm

I want to create a new node.js app in PhpStorm but it can't build it as `npm` requires root to install. I can't seem to find a way to make PhpStorm run `npm` as `su`.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing with sudo will likely result in more issues. I'd rather suggest making sure that your user (the one you run WebStorm with) has the right privileges in ~/.npm, and give it the needed permissions ( '`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm`' )

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I figured out, too.